# Android spinner with black text on a dark background

Tags: android, themes, spinner

For an Android activity with theme:

```
     <android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

and no other explicit colour properties, on a Motorola DroidX (Android version 2.3.340.MB810.Verizon.en.US), the spinner and button backgrounds are dark with black text although the main background is white.  On most other phones, spinner and buttons appear as black text on a light grey gradient background.

Am I doing something wrong, or might this be an Android or Motorola bug?

In any case, can anyone suggest a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design you own customized drawable for spinner background and apply to it.
For spinnerbackground.xml images you can refer the images from the SDK. recreate the images as per your design requirements

> "Android-sdk\platforms\android-9\data\res\drawable-hdpi\*.png"

spinnerbackground.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_disabled" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_normal" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_disabled_focused" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/wlbtn_dropdown_disabled" />
</selector>
```

then for spinner widget apply your custom drawable:

```
<Spinner android:background="@drawable/spinnerbackground"
         android:id="@+id/spinnerIDr"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </Spinner>
```

Comment: Thank you, Vinayak.B.  It's a good suggestion.  But the reason why I am wary of this approach is the risk of an app not conforming to a manufacturer's or user's theme.  I made the assumption that any platform would respect 'Theme.Light' in the context of an overall white on black or black on white approach etc.  The DroidX seems to be an exception in rendering it as black on dark grey.  Unfortunately I haven't got a Motorola DroidX to experiment with, and only discovered the problem from user feedback on the market.

Comment: Yea I agree with your comment, my suggestions is, anyway you are designing your app as per your design standards then make the complete design as per your standards. When platform allowing you to do this it will be a plus point for the developers. Who knows in future (Like DroidX) the themes will be in what designs. If you go with your customized way then you can ensure it will remain consistent permanently.

Comment: Thanks again.  You're right, it may be better to force the issue.  The app in question is PhoneTrack: in case anyone wants to contact me about readability problems with particular devices.