# Spinner invisible on black background

Tags: android

I want to place a spinner into a view. But for some reason, the spinner is invisible, but the button below it is visible:
[image]

This is the code. I can set a background for the spinner, but it does not look like a default spinner then.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/surfaceViewHolder">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/drive_mode_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
            android:textOff="@string/start"
            android:textOn="@string/stop"
            android:onClick="onToggleSensorClick"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why its displaced that way?

Comment: try setting `android:background="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"` to your spinner

Comment: `I can set a background for the spinner, but it does not look like a default spinner then.`

Comment: Please, use text to show your code, and not images.

Comment: if you change the spinners color or the background is it visible?

Comment: It's visible, but it does not look like a default spinner: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160129/wz8tzl8q.png

Comment: try this with custom background : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5141273/4409113

Comment: I think you should add default style by style="".

Answer (score 0):

You should add android:entries="@array/spinnerItems" to the spinner to show something inside as you made height wrap_content.

Comment: If you want define entries in code, you should change wrap_content to exact size. Because android first watch for xml configuration then codes you have implemented. I guess it does not update the spinner height after you set entries.

Comment: But with background it's shown (but not the "default" style)

Comment: Are you using default theme of the android?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using different theme with your Activity .Activity's theme affects the appearance of its control(i.e its view's color and shapes )